# how execute function one by one

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want fix code on JQuery, which open popup waiter, execute ajax load, and then close popup windows.
First version was this:

```
    $("#SearchInfo").click(function () {
    alert("1.Start function. Open waiter popup");
    OpenWaiterDialog();
    alert("2.Start execution ajax request");

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/searchParameterInBuildDefinition/SearchInfoByBuilds?nameTeamProject=" + $("#SelectorProjectForSearch").val() + "&searchmessage=" + $("#searchmessage").val(),
            data: "",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                var output = "";
                $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                    //console.log("======================");
                    //console.log("Id:" + response[i]);                
                    output += "<tr><td>" + response[i] + "</td></tr>";
                });
                $("#TableTestCases").show();
                $('#BodyTable').html(output);
            },
            dataType: "json"//set to JSON  

        })

    alert("3.Request finish. Close popup");

    CloseWaiterDialog();
});
```

When I execute this function, browser frozen (Microsoft Edge), and after received ajax data, show me message 3,1,2.

I tried short function:

```
        $.when($.when(OpenWaiterDialog()).then(SearchInfoInBuildDefinition())).then(CloseWaiterDialog());
```

But even in this case web page froze for ajax request, paint waiter popup, and can't close popup. 
How can I fix this. It's possible give bigger priority for UI?

Comment: Why not put your CloseWaiterDialog in the success function of you ajax call and make async true?

Comment: 1) remove the `async: false` property. It's really bad practice. If you check the console, the browser will even be telling you not to use it 2) Put `alert('3...')` and `CloseWaiterDialog()` call *inside* the `success` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `async:false`, just chain the `CloseWaiterDialog` to run in the `.always()` of the ajax call.

```
$("#SearchInfo").click(function () {
    OpenWaiterDialog();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/searchParameterInBuildDefinition/SearchInfoByBuilds?nameTeamProject=" + $("#SelectorProjectForSearch").val() + "&searchmessage=" + $("#searchmessage").val(),
        data: "",,
        dataType: "json"//set to JSON  
    }).then(function (response) {
        var output = "";
        $.each(response, function (i, item) {
            //console.log("======================");
            //console.log("Id:" + response[i]);                
            output += "<tr><td>" + response[i] + "</td></tr>";
        });
        $("#TableTestCases").show();
        $('#BodyTable').html(output);
    }).always(function(){
        CloseWaiterDialog();
    });
});
```